# Generate jpeg-YCbCr tiles in GeoTIFF file with JFIF format instead pure JPEG format

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, cloud-optimized-geotiff

Currently, my app creates GeoTIFF tiled files using following options:

- PROFILE=GeoTIFF
- TILED=YES
- BLOCKXSIZE=xxx
- BLOCKYSIZE=xxx
- COMPRESS=JPEG
- PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR
- JPEG_QUALITY=xx

However, some apps that use my served tiles does not working due to "invalid" JFIF format.

How can I force GDAL to ensure JFIF format in GeoTIFF tiles?

Comment: Give more information. What is wrong, how should it be? Why it has not been a problem for other COG users? Forcing different encoding would probably require code changes in how libjpeg is used.

Comment: Do you understand these considerations http://libtiff.maptools.org/TIFFTechNote2.html?

Comment: @user30184 jpeg tiles are stored using baseline DCT-based JPEG marker (0xFF, 0xC0) instead using APPn marker (0xFF, 0xEn) described in [Syntax and structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG). My idea is force gdal to ensure JPEG-File structure using JFIF-APP0 (0xFF, 0xE0 ...) as [File format structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format)

Comment: It is absolutely best to introduce your idea on the gdal-dev mailing list. Explain the advantages and if you plan to change the current behavior or to introduce a new option. Consider also what it would mean for existing applications. If there are some apps that do not read current tiles, can there be some other apps that would not read the new variant? Could it be possible to make "some apps" to accept the current tiles? There must be enormous amounts of GeoTIFFs produced this way during the last 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

Gdal library code forces not writing JFIF-APP0 marks on any JPEG tiled image.

In gdal/frmts/gtiff/libtiff/tif_jpeg.c (line 1972), changing

```
sp->cinfo.c.write_JFIF_header = FALSE
```

by

```
sp->cinfo.c.write_JFIF_header = TRUE
```

forces saving JFIF marks.